# Add javascript var to href

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have dropdown with different links, before that i have 2 radio buttons where you could select "mode".

```
<div class="radio">
  <label><input type="radio" name="mode" checked="checked" value="mode1">MODE1</label>
</div>
<div class="radio">
  <label><input type="radio" name="mode" value="mode2">MODE2</label>
</div>


<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Choose site
  <span class="caret"></span></button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a target="_blank" href="http://example.com/index.php?mode=">Site1</a></li>
    <li><a target="_blank" href="http://example.com/index.php?mode=">Site2</a></li>
    <li><a target="_blank" href="http://example.com/index.php?mode=">Site3</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

And i use this code snippet to detect what mode is selcted and add it to var mode:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var myRadio = $('input[name=mode]');
    myRadio.on('change', function () {
        var mode=myRadio.filter(':checked').val();
    });            
});
```

What i want to do is to add javascript var $mode to href tags.

href="http://example.com/index.php?mode={$mode}

How could i accomplish this ?

I think only way would be to do this with some javascript function ?
Its not possible to just "print" var to href ?

JSFIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/18683/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this fiddle I've modified for you: https://jsfiddle.net/so2fw1o4/1/

Add this to your `myRadio.on('change',` function

```
//here change the urls
    $('.dropdown-menu a').each(function(){
      $(this).attr('href', $(this).data('url') + mode)
    })
```

And you will need to add data attribute to each link to store initial link

```
<a target="_blank" data-url="http://site. com/index.php?mode=" href="http://site. com/index.php?mode=">Site1</a>
```

Comment: Thank you, this clears things up for me. 1 other question how to only apply this function for 1 div ? At the moment if i have multiple dropdowns it changes all hrefs. I only want to change one dropdown.

Comment: 1) add specific class to the on you want to change, say **.my-dropdown**
2) change code to **$('.dropdown-menu.my-dropdown a').each(function(){**

Comment: Thanks. But i cant seem to figure out where to add class, i tried creating new div with class mydropdown, i tried adding class to li and a. But did not work, maybe you can update fiddle ?

Comment: <ul class="dropdown-menu my-dropdown">

Answer (score 2):

> Use `data-*` attribute to keep static `href` value to be used later. `.change()` will trigger change event initially to set the value of `href` attributes.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var myRadio = $('input[name=mode]');
  myRadio.on('change', function() {
    var mode = myRadio.filter(':checked').val();
    $('ul.dropdown-menu a').prop('href', function() {
      return this.getAttribute('data-href') + mode;
    })
  }).change();
});
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="radio">
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="mode" checked="checked" value="mode1">MODE1</label>
</div>
<div class="radio">
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="mode" value="mode2">MODE2</label>
</div>


<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Choose site
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a target="_blank" href="http://site1.com/index.php?mode=" data-href="http://site1.com/index.php?mode=">Site1</a>
    </li>
    <li><a target="_blank" href="http://site2.com/index.php?mode=" data-href="http://site2.com/index.php?mode=">Site2</a>
    </li>
    <li><a target="_blank" href="http://site3.com/index.php?mode=" data-href="http://site3.com/index.php?mode=">Site3</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

[**Fiddle here**](https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/DTcHh/18685/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this :-

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var myRadio = $('input[name=mode]');
    myRadio.on('change', function () {
        var mode=myRadio.filter(':checked').val();
        $("ul.dropdown-menu li a").each(function(){
           $(this).attr('href',$(this).attr('href').split('?')[0] + "?mode=" + mode);
        });
    }).change(); //trigger on page load          
});
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/KartikeyaKhosla/DTcHh/18686/)

Comment: What about second attempt ?

Answer (score 0):

Although you already have some answers here, I figured I would post another alternative (not necessarily any better).

You could add a class to each link, handle their click events, and set the new window's location yourself to achieve a similar effect.

The following is a code snippet modifying the jQuery in your fiddle:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var myRadio = $('input[name=mode]');
  var mode = myRadio.filter(':checked').val(); // Initial setting

  myRadio.on('change', function () {
    mode=myRadio.filter(':checked').val();
  });

  $('.mode-link').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); //stop the click action

    // Check if the mode has been set
    if (mode) {
      // Create the href value
      var newHref = $(this).attr('href') + mode;

      // Open the new tab/window with the correct href value
      window.open(
        newHref,
        '_blank'
      );
    }
  });
});
```

I simply added the `mode-link` class to each `a` element in the dropdown, stored the radio button value change in a new variable `mode`, added the `click` event handler, and finally handled the click event to create the new href value and open a new tab/window with that location.

If you didn't want the new tab/window you could simply set `location.href = newHref` but this wouldn't mimic the new tab/window opening, hence why I use `window.open()`.

I have a modified sample here: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e0f51eg6/5/)